# Alternative of -moz-linear-gradient in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have a style having property that shows dark yellow color in all browsers except IE

```
backgroud: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FDE37A, #FFCC01) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
```

But in IE it shows that color as pink

Is their any alternative of moz-linear-gradient in IE?

Thanks

Comment: No, it should not be pink in IE or dark yellow in *all browsers*. You haven't shown us the actual code.

Comment: What are the "all browsers"? `-moz` will only really work in Firefox. You must have some other background style declaration elsewhere.

Comment: I am using IE8 in which it is not working fine, But I do't know it is working fine for all i.e chrome safari etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for IE,

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FDE37A', endColorstr='#FFCC01',GradientType=0 );
```

you can generate cross browser gradients using following link,

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

For IE, you should use the `-ms-` prefix; in which case, your code would look like this: `-ms-linear-gradient(center top , #FDE37A, #FFCC01) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent`. Just take into account that IE8 and older versions have little to no support for CSS3, and IE9's support is limited; however, gradients should work. Which version of IE are you testing this on?

Comment: I highly doubt IE's prefix is `-ie-`.

Comment: My bad. Corrected "-ie-" to "-ms-".

Comment: @Verandaguy: currently I am testing in IE8 and also needed for IE8+ as well, let me try it please

Answer (score 1):

For Gradients and Multiple backgrounds in IE browsers use **CSS3 PIE Backgrounds**
http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

For IE9 use - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

EDIT: 
Gradients are CSS3 features old IE browsers don't support it. If you are using

```
backgroud: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FDE37A, #FFCC01) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
```

Add it as -

```
background: yellow; //IE8 and 7 will to refer this property    
backgroud: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FDE37A, #FFCC01) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```